# Xcode check if core data is enabled

Tags: xcode

I have already started my project in Xcode and now i'm required  to use core data for saving user info.I don't know if it is enabled in my project and i want to check that.Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data **is not something you can simply toggle on or off**. You have to build a Core Data Stack in you app's code to use Core Data. Also, you will need a Data Model and `NSManagedObject`s.

To check wether there is any Core Data related code in your app yet search for things like `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSPersistentStore`, `NSManagedObjectModel` and so on. You can verify that you have a Data Model by checking wether your project contains a `*.xcdatamodeld` file.

I strongly suggest reading the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1) to get an understanding of what Core Data actually is and how to use it.